# Average value of an operator on vacuum state

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, harmonic-oscillator

I'm trying to calculate
$$<0|e^{a\hat{x}^2}e^{b\hat{x}}e^{c\hat{p}}|0>$$
where $a$, $b$ and $c$ are complex numbers, $\hat{x}$ is the position operator, $\hat{p}$ is momentum operator and $|0>$ refers to vacuum state (i.e. Fock state with 0 photons).

So far, I have tried direct expansion of exponential in Taylor series, playing with Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff sort of formulae, and trying to recognize known states, such as squuezed states in the formula I'm asking about. This efforts were unsuccessful, though. Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to Physics! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Assuming that all quantities are written in units of the harmonic oscillator natural length $\sqrt{\hbar/m\omega}$, and using the ground-state wavefunction $\psi_0(x)=\frac{1}{\pi^{1/4}}e^{-x^2/2}$, one can perform the average by inserting enough resolution of the identity with respect to $x$ and $p$, to obtain (whether all constants are correct is left as an exercise to the reader) :
$$\langle 0|e^{a\hat x^2}e^{b\hat x}e^{c\hat p}|0\rangle=\frac{e^{\frac{b^2+c^2-2 i b c-2 a c^2}{4(1-a)}}}{\sqrt{1-a}}.$$

Note that this average is valid only if $a<1$.

Comment: why the downvotes ?